# drf-spectacular post method not working with form field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I am using Django Rest Framework. And for documentation I am using `drf-spectacular`.

But the problem I am facing is that when I am trying to submit using form, I can not submit. But I can submit using JSON type normally.

**This Does not Work:**

[image]

**This Works:**

[image]

How can I make the form to work? It does not even let me submit the form. Also, How can I make the profile_pic as filefield?

Below is my code:

**settings.py**

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FileUploadParser',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}

SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'TITLE': 'Your Project API',
    'DESCRIPTION': 'Your project description',
    'VERSION': '1.0.0',
}
```

**serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from app_restaurant import models


class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Restaurant Create Serializer
    """
    class Meta:
        model = models.Restaurant
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'slug': {'read_only': True},
        }
```

**views.py**

```py
from rest_framework import generics
from app_restaurant import serializers, models
from app_user import apipermissions


# Create your views here.
class RestaurantCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Restaurant Creation View
    """
    permission_classes = [apipermissions.IsOwner]
    serializer_class = serializers.RestaurantSerializer
    queryset = models.Restaurant.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this option your SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS:

`'COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUEST': True,`

Answer (score 0):

Same here with application/x-www-form-urlencoded. While it works from curl. I am thinking of dropping the application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data options - as I only need JSON - entirely out of the html using css or javascript if I can..